# Omniscience is not good enough for all-seeing God

Tags: grammaticality, terminology

I am attempting to write a book on the missing perceptions and actions Jesus had with individuals during His time here on earth.

I am also adding to my "Inductive Studies" workbook on the Attributes of God a forth Omni Attribute of 'All Seeing.'  Omniscient could be used in place of 'all seeing,' however, the Hebrew word in the Old Testament is (ra-ah), is attributed to seeing things as God sees things.

I realize in Gods perspective that knowing is very close to seeing, however I think there should be a difference, because like in the cases of Jesus being confronted by indiviuals day in and day out, He seen and knew things, very close in succession and yet separate.

So, as the Godhead notice in Genesis, things are good after seeing them.

Question:
What would be an 'omni-' word for all-seeing?

Comment: Are you asking for a [tag:neologism]?

Comment: You seem to have lost track of your question. Exactly what are the  capabilities that you're claiming your god has (had) , and how do they differ from omniscient?  Is he a panopticon?  Does he instantly sense all events of all types?  Is the future known?   etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["omni"-prefixed word for "all seeing"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251616/omni-prefixed-word-for-all-seeing)

Answer (score 2):

*Omnivident* isn't in my dictionaries, but it would mean 'all-seeing,' on the model of *omnipotent*, *omniscient*, *omniparent*, etc. Moreover, a quick web search shows that some people are currently using it as a word.

If you want a more established English word, the closest thing that one of my dictionaries offers is the rather rare *omnipercipient*, which means 'perceiving all things.'

Comment: The OED has [*omnividence*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131226?redirectedFrom=omnividence#eid33491465) (*Obs*. the capacity of seeing all things.) as well as *omnividency* and *omnivision*, both of which it defines as "= *omnividence*"; if you want to add a link I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [***omnipercipient***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnipercipient). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> <sub><sup>ADJECTIVE</sup></sub>
>   Seeing or perceiving all things.

The noun form would be [*omnipercipience*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnipercipience).

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/258648)<sup>1</sup> also suggests that [*omnispective*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnispective) was once used this way, but its current meaning (as seen in Oxford Dictionaries, linked above) is quite different.

---

<sup>1</sup> The OED is subscription-based; if you don't already have a subscription, check with your local library, which may have access.

Answer (score 0):

omnispective -
Om`ni`spec´tive
a.  1.  Beholding everything; capable of seeing all things; all-seeing.

Comment: You should include a citation for the definition.